# Force bootstrap button group to scale into container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am attempting to have a display for multiple images with descriptions using a button cycling system. However, when I wrap the cycler in a container with a fixed width, the buttons overflow the container rather than fitting within it. How can I force it to scale down inside it instead?

[image: Overflow in horizontal view]

[image: Overflow in vertical view]

```html
<div class="container w-50">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="img-fluid" style="width: 100%" id="cycler">
                <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x800" alt="Volunteer Profile Page" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 bg-light p-0 mr-5" style="border-radius: 0.25rem;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" checked>
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary m-0 selected">Photograph 1</label>

                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check">
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary m-0">Photograph 2</label>

                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check">
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary m-0">Photograph 3</label>

                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check">
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary m-0">Photograph 4</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <p class="p-3">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi tempore laborum maxime sequi molestiae saepe soluta, quaerat dolorum ipsam incidunt aut amet nemo quis omnis veniam expedita voluptatum, laudantium in?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "Photograph" is the problem in "Photograph 1", etc. The box always needs to be big enough to fit that text in, so it can't resize down enough. As it's just placeholder text, you can simply change it to "P1", "P2", etc and this will solve the problem.

If you need that text, I would go with "Photo 1" and slightly decrease the font-size. This would also solve it.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I'll adjust the font-size dynamically, then. Don't know why I didn't thionk of that.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the simplest way is to use `text-truncate`...

```
         <div class="btn-group w-100 text-truncate" role="group">
               <input type="radio" class="btn-check" checked>
               <label class="btn btn-secondary m-0 selected text-truncate">Photograph 1</label>

               <input type="radio" class="btn-check">
               <label class="btn btn-secondary m-0 text-truncate">Photograph 2</label>

               <input type="radio" class="btn-check">
               <label class="btn btn-secondary m-0 text-truncate">Photograph 3</label>

               <input type="radio" class="btn-check">
               <label class="btn btn-secondary m-0 text-truncate">Photograph 4</label>
         </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/OA12kyBkGJ